# Http failure response

Tags: angular, symfony

I'm working with Symfony and angular to realize a mini project. I added a route to my routing.yml file to edit a user. In the frontend that is angular, I try to retrieve a user by its id but I get a 404 error.

```
No route found for "GET /user/NaN" (from "http://localhost:4200/edit-user")
```

here is the routing.yml file:

```
pr_manager_update:
    path:     /user/update/{id}
    defaults: { _controller: PrManagerBundle:User:update}
```

Angular service:

```
getUserById(id: number) {
  return this.http.get(Statique.USER_ID + '/' + id);
 }
static USER_ID = 'http://localhost/project-manager/backend/web/app_dev.php/user';
```

And the component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { eb_user } from 'src/app/classes/eb_user';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { CreateService } from 'src/app/services/create.service';
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-edit',
  templateUrl: './edit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./edit.component.scss']
})
export class EditComponent implements OnInit {

  user: eb_user[];
  updateForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
              private router: Router,
              private createService: CreateService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    let userId = localStorage.getItem("editUserId");
    if(!userId){
      alert("erreur")
      this.router.navigate(['liste-user']);
      return;
    }
    this.updateForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      id: [],
      nom: ['', Validators.required],
      prenom: ['', Validators.required],
      tel: ['', Validators.required],
      mail: ['', Validators.required],
      domaine: ['', Validators.required],
      //client: eb_user[];
      //x_eb_role : ['', Validators.required],
    });
    this.createService.getUserById(+userId)
        .subscribe(data => {this.updateForm.setValue(data);});
  }

  onSubmit(){
    this.createService.editUser(this.updateForm.value)
        .pipe(first())
        .subscribe(
          data =>{
            this.router.navigate(['liste-user']);
          },
         error => {
           alert(error);
         }

        );
  }

}
```

I expect the connection between the backend and the frontend to be done correctly

Comment: Your `userId` is probably not numeric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `userId` is probably not numeric, see the following example:

```js
let userId = "10"; // a numberic string
console.log(+userId); // will give a number 10

userId = "hello"; // a non numeric string
console.log(+userId); // will give NaN
```

The URL will anyway be a string and you don't need to parse userId to number which will eventually be concatenated with a string again, just do:

```
this.createService.getUserById(userId) // no +userId
        .subscribe(data => {this.updateForm.setValue(data);})
```

Modify the parameter type of the method getUserById():

```
getUserById(id: string | number) {
  return this.http.get(Statique.USER_ID + '/' + id);
}
```

Comment: I modified it but I get the following error:  No route found for "GET /user/id" (from "http://localhost:4200/edit-user")

Comment: @dakim236 Don't you need to have a route like: `/user/{id}` in your API?